# How to add every item as a new record without updating in laravel in cart

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question regarding Laravel and I am new to Laravel.

I am creating a website with has multiple products and each product can be customized. Every time I add the same product to the cart, it overwrites the previous record which has the same product id(as expected). In my case I want the new item in the cart, every-time a user adds the product to their cart even if they add the same item again. How can I achieve this?

```
if(request()) {              
    $cart = session()->get('cart');
    $cart[request()->product_id][(count(session()->get('cart')))] = [
        "name" => request()->name,
        "tel" => request()->tel,
        "email" => request()->email,
        "linkedin" => request()->linkedin,
        "slogan" => request()->slogan,
        "logo" => request()->logo,
        "qty" => request()->qty,
        "product_id" => request()->product_id,
    ]; session()->put('cart', $cart);
```

I am not able to achieve, my record overwrites if the product_id is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the product id as array key.
you can do like this

```
//Check if cart key exist in sessiom
if(Session::has('cart')) {
    //get cart and push the new product and put in cart session
    $cart = Session::get('cart'); 
    $cart->push($this->productToAddCart());
    Session::put('cart', $cart);     
}
else {
    $cart = Session::put('cart', collect($this->productToAddCart()));
}
```

and create function to get product array which returns your required values for cart

```
protected function productToAddCart() {
    return [
        'product_id' => request()->product_id,
        'name' => request()->product_name,
    
        ..add your other required fields
    ];
}
```

The cart created using Laravel Collection so you can use Eloquent Query Builder on it.

```
$cart = Session::get('cart'); 
$cart->all(); // like this
```